# ValueError at /register: The given username must be set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

ValueError at /register/
The given username must be set
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
The given username must be set

here's the views.py

```
def register_page(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
        print(username)
    return render(request, "auth/register.html", context)
```

This is sending None as a username and i dont know why?
`user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)`
 How to resolve this issue? It is not getting the username with POST method or there is some other mistake?

Comment: is it prints `form.cleaned_data` with all values ?

Comment: proper [mcve] please.

Comment: Also note that the `RegisterForm(request.POST or None)` is considered bad practice (even if it's a post request, `request.POST _can_ be empty), and even more so when you don't even test against `request.method` before trying to validate the form.

Comment: Please show the code for RegisterForm. Does it actually contain a `username` field?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='confirm password')` this is the class for Registering user

Comment: Well as you can surely see there, you have a `user` field but not a `username` field. So naturally trying to get the data for a field that doesn't exist is going to fail.

Comment: yes exactly that was an error but it gone. Appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are doing lots of things even though you are not in the POST case.
I suggest you check whether you are in POST or not.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

If you are in POST, you can retrieve the form with :

```
form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
```

if you are not in POST, you must send an empty form to the page with :

```
form = RegisterForm()
```

Then, after having checked that the form is valid, you can already create your new user.

```
user = User()
```

Note that you must import the class User with : `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Now you can retrieve the data from your form as you did, and assign it to your new empty User:

```
user.username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
user.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
```

For the password, you should encrypt it with :

```
user.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
```

Note that you must import the make_password method : `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`

After all this, you can save your new user to the database :

```
user.save()
```

Note that you should probably do the save into a `try: ... except` block in order to catch potential exception caused by IntegrityError if several users try to register with the same username or such, depending on the Integrity rules that Django uses for his User model by default (which I don't remember)

Finally, your view should look like that (or similar) :

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User()
            user.username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            user.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
            user.save()
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'auth/register.html', {'form': form})
```

It should work considering you made your imports, a proper RegisterForm, and a proper auth/register.html

Comment: Thank You for your effort to try to make it simple let me try this (y)

Comment: Thank you man it worked now i am having IntegrityError which I can solve.