# ValueError at /accounts/register The given username must be set

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-views, valueerror

veiws.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages
from travello.models import Destination
import traceback
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage




# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        
        
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            messages.info(request,'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')        
def register(request):
    
            if request.method == "POST":
                first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
                last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                email = request.POST.get('email')
                password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
                password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
                if password1 == password2:
                   if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                       messages.info(request,'Username taken')
                       return redirect('register')
                   elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                       messages.info(request,'EMAIL taken')
                       return redirect('register')
                   else:    
                    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password1, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
                    user.save();
                    print("User created")
                    return redirect('login')
                else:
                 messages.info(request,'password not matching...')
                 return redirect('register')
            else :
                return render(request, 'register.html')
            
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)            
    return redirect('/')

def postdestination(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            f = request.FILES["img"]
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(f.name, f)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
            name = request.POST['name']
            # img = request.POST['img']
            description = request.POST['description']
            price = request.POST['price']
            offer = request.POST.get('offer')
            
            if offer == "on":
                offer = True
            else:
                offer = False
            
            d = Destination.objects.create(name=name, desc=description,img=uploaded_file_url,price=price,offer=offer)
            d.save()
        except  Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'post_destination.html')
```

While registering this error is occurring. I'm using postgresql as DBMS .

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/register
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: ValueError
ValueError at /accounts/register
The given username must be set
```

Comment: Please take a look at this url, it may be helpful else reach back.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991221/valueerror-at-register-the-given-username-must-be-set

Answer (score 0):

You are using request.POST but you are not passing any form to it after.
You should explicitly pass the form in the different requests so that django will know what to handle.